# to find frequency of digits(0-9) in a string

Tags: c

My code for finding the frequency of digits in a character array in C is not giving the desired output.

```
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char str[n];
    int f[10],i,j,ns;
    gets(str);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        f[i]=0;
        for(j=0;j<strlen(str);j++)
        {
            ns=str[j]-'0';
            if(i==ns)
                f[i]+=1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",f[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter the string

```
1wjhue73b38409598
```

I am getting the output of frequency of (0-9):

```
1 0 0 2 1 1 0 1 2 2
```

Instead of frequency 1 for '1'.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It would be much simpler to do something like: `f[str[j] - '0']++`

Comment: @FiddlingBits yikes. There are letters in that string

Comment: @TimRandall Thanks for the catch.  How about: `if(isdigit(str[j])) f[str[j] - '0']++;`

Comment: Never use `gets`. It is deprecated.

Comment: What value did you enter for 'n' before entering the string? Because that's a classic security vulnerability

Comment: @TimRandall Didn't know that is possible...
where is `str` placed on the heap or miracuously stack ? (my guess heap, but with a weird syntax).
it sure aint ANSI C.

Comment: @Broman It's more than deprecated; It's *gone* as of C11. It is no longer part of the language standard library. Any implementations that still provides it do so at their own peril; the library no longer requires it *at all*, and implementations are free (and encouraged) to omit it.

Comment: @TomerW: Variable length arrays, see [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @TimRandall  when my input for n is 50.the output is something like this  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -48 -48  (both -48 and -48 are in different lines and all 0s on the 1st line

Comment: My question has been superseded by dbush's answer. You wouldn't have had a problem if your code had contained `char str[]="1wjhue73b38409598";` instead of the `gets` stuff.

Comment: But when i am not entering any value of n ,I am getting the output as mentioned in my question. and entering giving a value to n gives me ( 0 0 0..).so how is the former method giving a more accurate  output(except for frequency of first element)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Or rather, why you're saying it. We've established (below) the problems with your code as written above. I don't think there's any benefit to discussing exactly what it does when it gets specific inputs, because we already know what's wrong with it

Comment: @Tidem23 It has to do with mixing `scanf` and `gets`.  See the update to my answer.

Comment: @TimRandall i dont understand how entering a value of 'n' is a classic security vulnerability?can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you search for "buffer overflow attack" there is plenty of information. The problem is that you're trusting the user to tell you how long a string is going to be. There's nothing to stop them entering more data than they promised. And where is their data going to go? Onto your stack, quite possibly. This was my initial guess as to what was wrong, but dbush got to the truth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what happens when you mix `scanf` with `gets` / `fgets`.

The call to `scanf` is expecting a number.  When you enter "1wjhue73b38409598" as the input it reads the 1 at the start of the string and stops reading when it sees the "w".  So `n` gets set to 1.

Then `gets` immediately reads the remaining characters (i.e. "wjhue73b38409598") without prompting.  Since the 1 is not part of this string, it doesn't get counted.

There's another problem however.  Because `n` is set to 1, `str` can only hold 1 character.  So the `gets` call writes past the end of the buffer.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this *particular* case, things appeared to otherwise work, however a minor change to the code could change how undefined behavior manifests.

Even if you were to enter a proper value for `n` such as 50, the `scanf` call leaves a newline in the buffer.  The subsequent call to `gets` then immediately reads the newline and stops, so all of the counters are 0.

Use a fixed size buffer instead and use `fgets`, which can be given a maximum size to read, to read the string:

```
char str[50];
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
```